# Is the launcher responsible for sending broadcasts to AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android

I'm finding the behaviour of the widget I'm developing varies a lot from device to device.  In particular, the number and timing of broadcasts received by my `onReceive()` seem to differ, particularly shortly after a reboot, and one culprit I suspect is the launcher.

But is the launcher itself responsible for (or at least have some control over) the sending of these broadcasts?